# Divisiblilty & Prime Problems [GRE]

Tags: divisibility, gre-exam

> if j is divisible by 12 and 10, is j divisible by 24?
>
> Answer by either saying yes, no , or Can't be determined.

I approached this question as follow:

First i found the prime factors of both numbers

10: 5 * 2

12 : 3*2*2

Then i found out the prime factors of 24

24: 2*3*2*2

So i concluded from this since we need 3 2s and 1 3 the answer is yes.

However the book states that the answer is can't be determined because one of the 2s can be redundant. I am not sure about this reasoning can anyone explain me why? Also if you have some reliable source please present it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A counter-example is the number 60. 60 is divisible by 10 and 12 but is not divisible by 24.

Suppose you have a number n which is divisible by both 10 and 12. This means that there must be at least 2 twos in the prime decomposition of n (based on the prime decomposition of 10 and 12). Here you can see that it is not necessarily true that there are 3 twos that divide n.

Comment: for example if x is divisible by 28 and 15 it will also be divisible by 20 because we know for sure x has a prime of 5 and 2 2s at the least since it is divisible by 28 and 15. Similarly the question above shows we have the prime numbers required for 24.

Comment: @user1772052: $60=2 \ast 2 \ast 3 \ast 5$.  This is divisible by $10$ ($2 \ast 5$) and $12$ ($2 \ast 2 \ast 3$), but it is not divisible by $24$ ($2 \ast 2 \ast 2 \ast 3$).

Answer (score 1):

If $j$ is divisible by $12 = 2^2 \cdot 3$ and by $10 = 2 \cdot 5$, then we can certainly conclude it's divisible by $2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$, and so by $2^2 \cdot 3 = 12$. We *can't* conclude that it's divisible by $2^3$, though, since neither $12$ nor $10$ are.

But it's not always true that it's divisible by $2^3$; the number $60$ is a counterexample.

Comment: for example if x is divisible by 28 and 15 it will also be divisible by 20 because we know for sure x has a prime of 5 and 2 2s at the least since it is divisible by 28 and 15. Similarly the question above shows we have the prime numbers required for 24

Comment: @user1772052 The key point is that all the divisors of $28$ and $15$ are *relatively prime* to each other. But if, say $2$ is a divisor of a number and $4$ is a divisor of a number, we cannot conclude that $8 = 2 \cdot 4$ is a divisor.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by relatively prime?